# multiple table alignment in html

Tags: css, html

Hello I am a beginner in HTML and CSS. I created a multiple table tag to with Power description but I cant align the level2 and level3 table tag from Level1. Another query. How can I create another sets of Level's that will be under to no Power? but I'm not able to get the desired result.

actually the required is to create 8 sets of Level horizontally. The description name is fixed for individual boxes from L1-Sample1 to L3-Good.

Please see below my initial HTML code.

```html
    <tr>
      <div border: border= "2"; >
           With Power
      </div>  
    </tr> 
    <!--level1 -->
    <table border: border="1"; cellpadding: "1" >
      <tr>
       <td style="Background: Gray";>Level1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>L1-Sample1</td>
          <td>value</td>
          <td>value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>L1-sample2</td>
       <td>value</td>
          <td>value</td>
      </tr> 
       <tr>
       <td>L1-sample3</td>
       <td>value</td>
          <td>value</td>
      </tr> 
       <tr>
       <td>L1-sample4</td>
       <td>value</td>
          <td>value</td>
      </tr>  
    </table>
    <!---level2 -->
    <table border: border="1"; cellpadding: "1" >
      <tr>
       <td style="background: green";
                     >Level2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>L2-sample1</td>
          <td>value</td>
          <td>value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>L2-sample2</td>
       <td>value</td>
          <td>value</td>
      </tr> 
       <tr>
       <td>L2-sample3</td>
       <td>value</td>
          <td>value</td>
      </tr> 
       <tr>
       <td>L2-sample4</td>
       <td>value</td>
          <td>value</td>
      </tr>  
       <tr>
      <td>L2-sample5</td>
       <td>value</td>
          <td>value</td>
      </tr>
        <td>L2-sample6</td>
       <td>value</td>
          <td>value</td>
      </tr>    
      <td>L2-sample7</td>
       <td>value</td>
          <td>value</td>
      </tr>    
    </table>
    
    <!--Level3---->
    <table border: border="1"; cellpadding: "1" >
      <tr>
       <td style="background: Blue";
                     >Level3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>L3-Good</td>
          <td>value</td>
          <td>value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>L3-Bad</td>
       <td>value</td>
          <td>value</td>
      </tr> 
       
    </table>
    
    <!--create another sets of Level under no Power-->
    <table>
    <tr>
      <div border: border= "2"; >
           No Power
      </div>  
    </tr> 
    </table>
```

Please see below sample image.
[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgNQl.jpg)

Comment: It would be good if you can add the desired result as an image for us to visualize what you want.

Comment: not clear what you are looking for....what is `8 sets of Level horizontally.` mean...

Comment: Your last table has invalid HTML

Comment: There is a lot of invalid code here. You're missing colspan tags for rows that should span all 3 columns. `<table border: border="1"; cellpadding: "1" >` should look something like `<table border="1" cellpadding="1" style="border:1px solid black;padding:1em;" >`. If you use a proper editor like `Netbeans` it will tell you where your errors are in your code, depending on the Doctype. https://netbeans.org/downloads/

Comment: Just added a sample image for the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

This will works, apply this CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
} 

table tr td {
    width: 120px;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are useing div tag in tr so remove and use `<tr> <th> </th> </tr>`

Answer (score 0):

Add `table{ width: 100%;}` or any width of your choice for equal table width.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `table`...you will need to use its elements `tbody`, `tr`, `td` properly also its attributes like `col-span`, `row-span`, `border` `cellpadding` etc...

> ***[Take reference for table here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)***

Also when you write markup, its better to validate your code...you can use **[html validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)** to validate it

You will need to wrap your tables inside a main table to align them like below

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

table table td {
  padding: 10px;
}

td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">
                <h3>With Power</h3>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" style="background: gray;">Level1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L1-Sample1</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L1-sample2</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L1-sample3</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L1-sample4</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- level2 -->
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" style="background: green;">Level2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L2-sample1</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L2-sample2</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L2-sample3</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L2-sample4</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L2-sample5</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L2-sample6</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L2-sample7</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Level3 -->
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" style="background: blue;">Level3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L3-Good</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L3-Bad</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">
                <h3>No Power</h3>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" style="background: gray;">Level1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L1-Sample1</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L1-sample2</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L1-sample3</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L1-sample4</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- level2 -->
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" style="background: green;">Level2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L2-sample1</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L2-sample2</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L2-sample3</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L2-sample4</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L2-sample5</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L2-sample6</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L2-sample7</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Level3 -->
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" style="background: blue;">Level3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L3-Good</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>L3-Bad</td>
              <td>value</td>
              <td>value</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Bhuwan, Thank you very much for this very informative html code. I would like to add table tag to create another sets of h3 tag (with power and no power to complete the 8 sets (with power,nopower,with power,nopower etc ). my question is the code html code will be too long to complete the 8 table tag. is there any effect or is there any approached to shorten the codes. by the way, I edit the sample image with the actual desired result.

Comment: I'm thinking  this would be a real pain to create and manage manually. Some suggestion is to make this in Java script which I think is applicable because i will inject the code to spotfire but the main concern is I'm just starting to learn Java script.

Comment: @Jov see its a very big task...you have two option, either write whole code in html or create a json with all data and retrieve data using javascript...but for that you will have to learn how to get data from a json using javascript first...

Comment: yes it can be done in spotfire and I can retrieve the data. I already write the whole code in HTML but i have a missing element from the structure the main header and sub main header. where i can add this in HTML? please see the desired sample image. thanks.

Comment: just to share with you this code if this is correct . thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share with you this code if this is correct to create the main and submain. THanks.

```
  <tbody>
  <center><h2 style="width:20%; text-align:center">Main</h2></center>
    <p style="text-align: center; width:50%; display: inline-block;  border: 1px solid #000;">Main1</p>
    <p style="text-align: center; width:49%;  display: inline-block;  border: 1px solid #000;">Main2</p> 
    <tr>
       <div>
        <p style="text-align: center; width:25%; display: inline-block;  border: 1px solid #000;">submain1</p>
        <p style="text-align: center; width:25%;  display: inline-block;  border: 1px solid #000;">submain2</p> 
        <p style="text-align: center; width:25%; display: inline-block;  border: 1px solid #000;">submain3</p>
        <p style="text-align: center; width:25%;  display: inline-block;  border: 1px solid #000;">submain4</p> 
         </div>
    </tr>
```